# Saving "likes" database design (Parse)

Tags: database, database-design, parse-platform, database-schema

Im using Parse to save data from my social network. So far I have three class: **Users**, **Posts**, and **Relationships**. I want the user to be able to like a post.

Should I create a new table for **Likes**. If so, then on my storyboard page I would have to query through **Relationships** to get the user followers, then **Posts** to get the posts from the followers, and then **Likes** to get the likes from those posts?

Is it efficient to have three API requests to parse on one page. I feel like this will slow down performance but I'm not sure how else to save likes.

Another thing is, I would like to display a notifications tableView. So all likes and requested follows. So Im guessing I would save likes in **Relationships** and just query through it twice on the storyboard to first get followers, then likes. And on the notification page, have one class to query though once to get all recent notifications.

What are your suggestions? 
Thanks.

Comment: can you show what your Relationships table looks like

Comment: @Daveo its a simple table. Just three columns. A **userA**, **userB**, and **confirm**. For a userA request to follow userB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is sort of a broad question so there is no way that I could say for sure, but I do have a couple suggestion that you can do with parse.com.

1. Use the local datastore: You can save all of the likes that the user has in the local datastore as well as in the cloud of your application. So, for instance, you create the like when the user likes something, save it to the cloud, and then pin it to the local datastore. That way, you can efficiently query all of the likes that your user has created without using an API request. But in the event the user logs into the app somewhere else, you also have the likes in the cloud to retrieve. So, I would create a new table for likes.
2. You could use a join table to implement the followers, so, you could also pin the followers of the user to the local datastore like you would for a like. This is like is done in the Parse.com anypic tutorial.
3. I would also have another table for notifications. In cloud code, you could even update how many notifications the user has with an afterSave method, and then get all the notifications through a query when requested by the user.